# Where is the info from a windows balloon error report logged?

Tags: windows-7, event-viewer

I just got a delayed write failed error in a balloon notification. I did not have time to read which file was concerned and now I am digging through event viewer with no luck so far. So are those balloons logged someplace and if yes where ?

Windows 7 Pro x64

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to locate it.
It is under `Windows Logs > System` and you have to filter for Event ID ***26***.

Using find will return no results in a genuine windows good-for-nothing style :

[image]

Comment: +1 "Using find will return no results in a genuine windows good-for-nothing style"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is. The balloon is just a notification box and can be used by many software programs and as such it doesn't have it's own log.

Maybe event viewer will shed some light on your issue.

Comment: Please read question carefully

Comment: It should be in the Event Log. Especially if it was a Delayed Write Failure, since there's a specific event for that:  "Event 50, NTFS: 
{Delayed Write Failed} Windows was unable to save all the data for the file . The data has been lost. This error may be caused by a failure of your computer hardware or network connection. Please try to save this file elsewhere."